# Running a task in parallelto maven install

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, maven-install-plugin

I looking for ways to improve build time for my maven build.

I was following this suggestion ([Speed up maven](http://bosy.dailydev.org/2009/02/speed-up-your-maven-build-four-times.html)) to rename the target folder to a different name and then proceed with the install goal and thus avoid the time it takes to clean.

However this leaves me with a folder that still needs to be cleaned at some stage.  I was hoping that I could automate the removal of this renamed folder as a second process that runs in parallel with the install phase.

I haven't been able to find any information on whether it is possible or not.

Cheers for the help,

Ferg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box feature that would do that. Also the antrun plugin seems not to have an option to fork the process and run in parallel.

maybe ant itself can do that within the build script?

Maven 3 supports parallel builds: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/parallel-builds-in-maven-3.html - that might help to speed things up (but depends on the plugins you are using).